# Accidentally reset .vimrc vim is still open: Possible to get recover .vimrc in memory?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to get a list of all the commands vim execute. I used `:mkvimrc` and that was helpful, but what would be better is if I could recover the commands that were executed, but I realize that is improbable, so I want to recover as much as possible while I still have vim open.

Getting the commands and functions would be helpful as well. For now, I'm going through it manually.

I should say that I do have a `.vim` folder with a directory structure of sub `*.vim` files and I do have plugins.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you could use `:set` to see the variables that have been set.

Comment: What did you accidentally do? Did you edit your .vimrc in Vim and want to undo those changes?

Comment: I have my vim files in a .git repository and while I was writing a script, I happened to `git reset --hard`, lol. But with vim still being loaded, everything is actually saved in one way or another. I'm going to answer this question to detail how to figure out what was lost using `redir`, `diff`, and patience. Unless you have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what you want but the `-w` startup-option may be helpful.

`:h -w`

```
                            *-w*
-w {scriptout}  All the characters that you type are recorded in the file
        "scriptout", until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want
        to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or
        ":source!".  When the "scriptout" file already exists, new
        characters are appended.  See also |complex-repeat|.
        {scriptout} cannot start with a digit.
        {not in Vi}

                            *-W*
-W {scriptout}  Like -w, but do not append, overwrite an existing file.
        {not in Vi}
```